# Attached object collides with environment

Tags: ros, collision, collision-detection, collision-object

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I added an object into the world and attached it to the robot as described in this [moveit-tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html).
As in the tutorial stated I attached the object with this piece of code:

```
ROS_INFO("Add an object into the world");

planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects);
sleep(5.0)
group.attachObject(co.id)
```

This all works fine, but while moving the robot with the attached object, collisions of this attached object and other objects in the environment are not detected. In fact, the object seems not attached while the robot is moving. It just pops up again at the target pose.

Anybody knows how a collision check can be achieved? (The attached object should be handled as part of the robot after being attached)

Thanks and regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205683/attached-object-collides-with-environment/) by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-04-23**:
Anybody an idea how to achieve it? I also tried the publisher from this [tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Environment_Representation/ROS_API#Advertise_the_Attached_Collision_Object_Topic). But there I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I think I found an answer myself now.
When attaching the object, I only tried it without the real robot, until now. There, no collision at all was recognized between the attached object and the surrounding as stated above.

Since today I can test it with the real robot and there it seems to work perfectly. Without the real robot the ee_link was not published sufficiently and therefore the attachment did not work properly. At least this is my guess.

So in the end, the piece of code I posted above and which I took from the tutorial works perfectly fine.

---

Originally posted by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) with karma: 236 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0